# Prove that $\mathbf{S}^n\to \mathbf{RP}^{n}$ is a local diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

This question came up on my differential geometry test, and even after I am still struggling.

> Let $i:\mathbf{S}^n\hookrightarrow \mathbf{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ be the canonical injection and $p:\mathbf{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbf{RP}^n$ be the canonical surjection. Prove that $p\circ i$ is a local diffeomorphism.

I know (but I still don't understand why) I have to prove that the differential of $p\circ i$ induces an isomorphism between the tangent spaces $T_x(\mathbf{S}^n)$ and $T_{p(x)}(\mathbf{RP}^n)$, but I don't get any further.

Could someone give any help?

Answer (score 1):

First, we have a well-defined map between two manifolds. Second, note that for a nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the kernel $K$ of $d_xp: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow T_{p(x)}\mathbb{RP}^n$ is exactly $\mathbb{R}x$ (use a chart if you aren’t convinced), so that, if $\|x\|=1$, $d_xi(T_xS^n) \oplus K=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

It follows from “standard linear algebra” that $d_xp_{|d_xi(T_xS^n)}$ is surjective, and thus that $p \circ i$ is a submersion. Since the manifolds have the same dimension, we have a local diffeomorphism.